# Implementational difference between h/w and s/w interrupt

Tags: operating-system

I know what is the difference between hw and sw interrupt.
The question is the implementational difference.
I know we read a interrupt vector and execute the interrupt service routine.
But what is the difference between them?
This question is for graduate school entrance interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the timing of a HW interrupt is dictated by the HW and the timing of a SW interrupt is determined programmatically by the operating system.

SW interrupt delivery will take place within some kind of HW interrupt handler (e.g., the timer handler).